# sticky footer with responsive website

Tags: css, responsive-design, sticky-footer

I have tried almost all the techniques to apply sticky footer to my site i am using **Gumby Responsive** 12 column 960 grid system but my page always show a lot of extra space after my footer  here is the link to the [PROBLEM Page](http://www.coffeedesign.net/derek/demo.html)

Comment: browser? and unless you already fixed it I don't see a space (FF 14).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem only exists if you activate JS. No such bottom margin when you deactivate it. So the problem is voluntarily caused by an instruction somewhere in a script.